# CSS Help: Image renders correctly in FF and Chrome, not IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm working on a website for a friend of mine and I'm having a bit of a CSS nightmare.  The URL is http://www.bike4haiti.com.

In Firefox and Chrome, there is a Haitian flag that appears in the top right corner of the top banner. In IE, however, it appears as a thin vertical line along the right edge, beginning at the top of the menu and descending past where the content section begins.  The CSS class is quite simple code:

```
img.rightfloat
{
float:right;
padding-left:1px;
padding-bottom: 1px;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-top: 1px;
}
```

My guess is that it is one of the other CSS elements causing the problem, but I have no idea which one.  I tried using the <kbd>F12</kbd> tool, but I had no luck finding the problem.

Help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set your first anchor to float:left; you already have the image floating so then just clear them with `#topmenu{float:none; clear:both}`

that should do it. you'll probably want to tinker with margins for spacing.

Answer (score 0):

You have a your width set to nothing  (`width=""`) in your `<img>` tag.

Comment: I *just* fixed that (validated the site on w3.org), but now, while the whole image appears, it is not in line with the cyclist image anymore.

Comment: I don't see any difference between IE and FF.  Also, your site doesn't validate as proper HTML5 http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bike4haiti.com%2F